# Error with PIP / Installing Buster

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem when installing [Buster](https://github.com/axitkhurana/buster) via PIP.

I think that the problem is related with Python. PIP choose Python2 but how can PIP use Python 3?

Here is the error in the command line after `pip install buster`;
`Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_felixinx/buster/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZR6weF-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_felixinx/buster
Storing debug log for failure in /home/felixinx/.pip/pip.log`

And here is the log (`/home/felixinx/.pip/pip.log`);

*Too long so I put it in Github Gist...* [pip.log](https://gist.github.com/felixinx/c278377ae35a0e32b595)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installation is failing because lack of permissions.

> ```
> creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buster
> error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buster': Permission denied
> ```

Did you install it with **sudo**?:

> sudo pip install buster

Comment: You know what? Its work! Thanks